# command which works like ~ (tilde) symbol to represent some directory

Tags: shell, directory, cd-command

`cd ~/scripts`. This will go into scripts directory in my home. 
Similar to this, I want some "alias" kind of setting, which will allow me 
to enter some other directory so that, 
`cd xxx/mywork` -> will go into the "mywork" directory /home/work/software. I want the command to set `xxx` to `/home/work/software`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what shell you're using, but `zsh` has built-in support for this.  It's called [named directories](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide02.html#l20).

To set this up, add code like the following to .zshrc:

```
mywork=/home/work/software  #set variable
: ~mywork    #Reference variable with a tilde in a no-op statement
```

Then you can use it at the command line like this:

```
$ cd ~mywork
```

Or this:

```
$ cd ~mywork/sub/directories
```

The full explanation for how/why the syntax of setting this up works can be found here: [named directories](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide02.html#l20).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like setting `CDPATH` could get you close to what you are
asking:

```
cd

    cd [-L|[-P [-e]] [-@] [directory]

    Change the  current working directory to  directory.  [...] If
    the shell variable CDPATH exists, it is used as a search path:
    each directory name in CDPATH  is searched for directory, with
    alternative  directory names  in CDPATH  separated by  a colon
    (‘:’).  If directory begins with a slash, CDPATH is not used.
```

This way, if you have `/home/work` in your `CDPATH`, then `cd
software` will get you in `/home/work/software`.

If you require something closer to the specific question, perhaps
setting a directory with symbolic links and putting that directory
would be even better. E.g., `mkdir ~/.links`, then `CDPATH=~/.links`,
and then, inside `~/.links`, create a symbolic link `mywork` to
`/home/work/software`. Then `cd mywork` should get you there.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you are asking for, but you may want to take a look at [Z](https://github.com/rupa/z/) (works in `bash` and `zsh`) which tracks your most used directories, based on 'frecency' and let you jump around.

In your example it would be something like:

```
z software
```

and it would probably change the directory to:

```
 /home/work/software
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed the suggestion here:
http://jeroenjanssens.com/2013/08/16/quickly-navigate-your-filesystem-from-the-command-line.html
and never looked back.  The key to this utility is that "cd" will follow symbolic links to directories, and a shell function which looks something like:

```
export JJPATH=$HOME/.jjlinks    
function jj {
    cd -P "$JJPATH/$1" 2>/dev/null || echo "No such link: $1"
}
```

In the directory $HOME/.jjlinks you stash all the symbolic links you like.  There are other simple shell functions to make such a link to the deeply nested directory you currently find yourself.

I used "jj", in honor of the author of this suggestion, (plus that's where my right index finger is most of the time), and so:

```
 jj pj7
```

immediately changes my directory to "~/projects/sequence/hepatocyte/seq_783/bin/"

Answer (score -1):

I think this utility might be what you are looking for:
http://micans.org/apparix/

Comment: We’re looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context.  Generally, an answer should explain how to solve the problem rather than just mentioning a tool; please explain why you’re recommending it as a solution, and see [How do I recommend software in my answers?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5329/354511).